# unable to import a psd file correctly in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-vectordrawable, psd

I imported two PSD files in android studio, suddenly I find out that one of them works correctly as shown in the pictures
[image]

[image]

and one other PSD imported the same way doesn't work as shown in the pictures
[image]
[image]

I wonder what could be the reason for that honestly, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the problem but maybe this will help you: [Error importing Vector Asset into Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607647/error-importing-vector-asset-into-android-studio)

Comment: I've read what you have suggested but this doesn't solve my issue